# decode an mp3 to a stream of ints

Tags: c++, c, audio

I'm looking for an easy to use lib that will convert an MP3 file to a sequence of int values (and the reverse), preferable without having to dump them all into RAM. A "decode the next 16kB into this buffer" like API would be ideal.

I need C or simple C++ bindings.

A MP3<->RAW filter CLI tool would work but I'd rather not have to keep uncompressed files on disk.

Answer (score 4):

Try [`libmad`](http://www.underbit.com/products/mad/) or ffmpeg's [`libavcodec`](http://ffmpeg.org/). Both should meet your requirements. The ancient `mp3lib` which was originally derived from/part of (?) `mpg123` has also been resurrected in `mplayer` with new development and perhaps has the best performance, but probably the ugliest code. :-)

Comment: Looking... Do you by chance happen to know of some good tutorials? If you don't I'll muddle through but I'd rather not.

Answer (score 0):

I created a .NET wrapper for mpg123 for use in my projects, and posted it to SourceForge.

It is here.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/mpg123net/

So you say you need it for C/C++ - ok, i posted it so you can check out my sample, that has so little code that is enough for initializing decoder and putting it to work for you.